# The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    //A widget to display before the current query in the AppBar.
    return IconButton(
      icon: const BackButtonIcon(),
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }
```

I tried create a close button that closes the search page and returns to the underlying route.

Comment: I guess the close method expect a String value as the second parameter.

Comment: Could you help with what I need to put as second parameter

Comment: A String variable. What the use of the close function and what the use of this second parameter? Do you have the code of this function?

Comment: Close is not a built in function of Flutter. So if you don't have create one to makes what you want, i think its not the function you want. `Navigator.of(context).pop()` is the Flutter build in function to close a view, try it.

Comment: ``close(context, null);`` Here, the second parameter accepts a value of ``String`` type but you're passing ``null``. Pass a string value. Also, if you could add the code of this method/fn, we could help you..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you used `Navigator.of(context).push()` or `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed()` before then you can use `Navigator.of(context).pop()` to close the route you created therefore Navigating back. Just make sure you don't pop the HomePage of your app.